# How can I delete a self-defined node and let it be nullptr in the function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class node
{
public:
    node* next;
    int val;
};

void func(node* root)
{
    node* p=root->next;
    delete p;
    p=nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    node* root=new node();
    node* nxt=new node();
    root->val=1;root->next=nxt;
    nxt->val=2;nxt->next=nullptr;
    
    func(root);    
    cout<<(nxt==nullptr)<<endl;//false
    cout<<(root->next==nullptr)<<endl;//false
}
```

How can I modify the `func()` to let last two line output 1?You can only delete `nxt` through `root` in `func()`.

**Edit:**

At first I hold the thought that `root->next` and `nxt` are exactly one thing since `root->next=nxt`.The fact is that `root->next` is just a copy of `nxt`.They have same value but are stored in different memory.In other words, they are two different pointer but point to the same memory where stores a `node` with `val==2` and `next==nullptr`.Thus it's impossible to delete `nxt` through `root`.And the same mistake happened in `func()`.

I modify the code to show the similarity and difference between `root->next` and `nxt`.

```
int main()
{
    node* root=new node();
    node* nxt=new node();
    root->val=1;root->next=nxt;
    nxt->val=2;nxt->next=nullptr;

    //point to same memory
    cout<<(root->next)<<endl;
    cout<<(nxt)<<endl;
    cout<<"---------"<<endl;
    //stored in different memory
    cout<<&(root->next)<<endl;
    cout<<&nxt<<endl;
    
}
```

And get output like this:

```
0x7219b0
0x7219b0
---------
0x7219a0
0x61ff08
```

What's more,I find that `root->next` subtract `&(root->next)` is always `0x10`.In my opinion,the first value is where the node with `val==2` is stored,the second value is a memory in the node with `val==1`.I guess it's because the two node is allocated almost the same time,so the operating system allocate them in a contiguous segment of memory.

Hope this can help other beginner.

Comment: In order to figure out, you just need to simply understand something that's very very simple, and very very basic. Not just in C++, but in any modern programming language, when you do something like `a=b`, and then later change `a`, it has absolutely no difference whatsoever to `b`, only `a`. So, if you `delete p`, and then set it to `nullptr`, this makes no difference whatsoever to wherever `p` "came from". If you want to do something to that, it's up to you to make that happen. And with that, the answer to your questions should be fairly obvious, no?

Comment: In your function `func`, `p` is a **copy** of `root->next`.  They initially have the same value, but changing `p` does not change `root->next`.  You can confirm this in a debugger or by adding `cout<<(root->next==nullptr)` inside `func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `func()`, `p` is its own unique variable. In your example, it holds a *copy* of the address held in `root->next`.  So, whatever you do to `p` itself, will not effect `root->next` in any way.  However, when you are calling `delete p`, you are destroying the `Node` object that both `p` and `root->next` are pointing at.  You are setting `p` to `nullptr` (which is redundant since `p` goes out of scope immediately afterwards), but you are leaving `root->next` dangling.

To fix `func()` so that the `(root->next==nullptr)` condition can become true in `main()`, you have two choices:

1. get rid of `p` and just act on `root->next` directly:

   ```
   void func(node* root)
   {
       delete root->next;
       root->next = nullptr;
   }
   ```
2. make `p` be a *reference* to `root->next` rather than a *copy*:

   ```
   void func(node* root)
   {
       node* &p = root->next;
       delete p;
       p = nullptr;
   }
   ```

But, nothing that `func()` does can affect the `nxt` variable in `main()` at all, since `nxt` is local to `main()` and `func()` has no concept that `nxt` exists.  That is why the `(nxt==nullptr)` condition can never become true in your example.  In fact, the `nxt` variable does not need to even exist at all, eg:

```
class node
{
public:
    int val;
    node* next = nullptr;
};

void func(node* root)
{
    node* &p = root->next;
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    node* root = new node{1};
    root->next = new node{2};
    
    func(root);    
    cout << (root->next == nullptr) << endl; // true
}
```